# Possible to register NullObject implementation as a fallback for a generic interface?

Tags: c#-4.0, design-patterns, generics, dependency-injection, autofac

We use a lot of Generics in our code. For example `ICommandHandler<T> where T is ICommand`, `ICommandValidator<T>` etc etc

Not everything has a ICommandValidator implementation. I was looking to use the NullObject pattern so that I could provide a fall back option to avoid having to test if validator is null.

For example

```
public class NullObjectCommandValidator : ICommandValidator<ICommand>
{
    public bool IsValid(ICommand command)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

We register all like:

```
    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
        .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(ICommandValidator<>))
        .InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

I was hoping to be able to register the NullObjectCommandValidator as a default for any ICommandValidator that didn't have a concrete implementation using a process like registering all other ICommandValidators<> and then registering the Null version at the end and preserving existing defaults.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change `NullObjectCommandValidator` to a generic type `NullObjectCommandValidator<TCommand>`. This way you can register it as follows:

```cs
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(NullObjectCommandValidator<>))
    .As(typeof(ICommandValidator<>));
```

`NullObjectCommandValidator<TCommand>` looks like this:

```cs
public class NullObjectCommandValidator<TCommand> : ICommandValidator<TCommand>
{
    public bool IsValid(TCommand command)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Now I can kill a bunch of if statements :)